# findByIdAndRemove is not a function error

Tags: node.js, mongoose, error-handling, model, mongoose-schema

```
router.delete('/:id', (req,res)=>{
    Category.findByIdAndRemove(req.params.id).then(category=> {
        if(category){
            return res.status(200).json({success: true, message: 'the category is deleted'})
        }
        else{
            return res.status(404).json({success: false , message: "category not found"})
        }
    }).catch(errror(err=>{
        return res.status(400).json({success: false, error : err})
    }))
})
```

I tried replacing the findByIdAndRemove with findByIdAndDelete, the record get deleted but a undefined error showed and the server crash.

Comment: Are you using mongoose v8? The findoneandremove is now removed.
https://mongoosejs.com/docs/migrating_to_8.html#removed-findoneandremove

Comment: the `catch` block is wrong. Get the error in catch like: `.catch(err => {...})`

Answer (score 0):

```
router.delete('/:id', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const category = await Category.findByIdAndDelete(req.params.id);
        if (category) {
            return res.status(200).json({ success: true, message: 'The category is deleted' });
        } else {
            return res.status(404).json({ success: false, message: 'Category not found' });
        }
    } catch (error) {
        return res.status(400).json({ success: false, error: error.message });
    }
});
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Use `findByIdAndDelete()` rather than `findByIdAndRemove()`. `findByIdAndRemove()` is depricated.